# Sofa/eloquence Call to a member function make() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am using [Sofa/eloquence package](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence)

The problem is when I use search

```
$users = USER::search($input)->get();
```

I get this error

> production.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a
>   member function make() on null in
>   /var/www/test/vendor/sofa/eloquence/src/Builder.php:77

I m using laravel 5.3, eloquence 5.3.3

I also already added this to config/app.php

> Sofa\Eloquence\ServiceProvider::class,

On my model

```
use Eloquence {replicate as private replicateEloquence;}
use Sluggable {replicate as private replicateSluggable;}

    public function replicate (array $except = null)
    {
         $this->replicateEloquence();
         $this->replicateSluggable();
    }
protected $searchableColumns = ['name'];
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix my problem

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't followed the installation instructions.

> Add Eloquence trait to the model - it's entry point for other extensions and is required for them to work.

Without that, this will fail.

Comment: I added the model code, on the question. Its working on localhost, but not on live server

Comment: @TomKur PHP version mismatch most likely.

Comment: I am using php7 on live server, is PHP7 incompatible with sofa/eloquence:5.3.3 ?

Comment: It is not, but check the semver exactly between the 2. Also what's the error on the production server?

Comment: The error on live server is production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function make() on null in /var/www/test/vendor/sofa/eloquence/src/Builder.php:77

Comment: @TomKur Perhaps your production server hasn't `composer dumpautoload` correctly.

Comment: there are these warning when installing eloquence and when composer dump-autoload.

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PHPUnit_Framework_MissingCoversAnnotationException" was found in both "/var/www/test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/PHPUnit_Framework_MissingCoversAnnotationException.php" and "/var/www/test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/MissingCoversAnnotationException.php", the first will be used.

Comment: and this warning

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "PHPUnit_Framework_CoveredCodeNotExecutedException" was found in both "/var/www/test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/CoveredCodeNotExecutedException.php" and "/var/www/test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/PHPUnit_Framework_CoveredCodeNotExecutedException.php", the first will be used.